# Microsoft Translator API gets stuck

Tags: java

I am using the java Microsoft Translator API and am experiencing a problem where the Translator becomes stuck; doesn't translate and doesn't throw any exceptions. I have tried using the Future method to detect a timout, but even that doesn't do anything. The code stops without any exceptions. Here is my code. Is there anything wrong and what can I do to fix it.

```
import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;
import com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate;

public class Translate
{
 public static String translate (String word)
 {
   Translate.setClientId("My ID");
   Translate.setClientSecret("My Secret");

   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

   Callable<String> task = new Callable<String>()
   {
    public String call()
    {
     try
     {
      String translatedWord = Translate.execute(currentWord, Language.FRENCH, Language.ENGLISH);
      return translatedWord;
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
      return "I don't know";
     }
    }
   };

   Future<String> future = executor.submit(task);
   try
   {
    String result = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
   } 
   catch (Exception e) 
   {
    System.out.println("failed");
    future.cancel(true);
    return "I don't know";
   }
 }

 public static void main (String args[])
 {
  String frenchWord = "Bonjour";
  String englishWord = translate(frenchWord);
  System.out.println(englishWord);
 }
}
```

When I replace the translate line in the call method, it all works well. However, Translate.execute(...) seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: "I am using the java **Microsoft** Translator API..." well there's your problem.

Comment: What do you suggest then. Google Translator API didn't work

Comment: I was just making a joke.

Comment: I do appreciate your humour, but an answer is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch & log **Throwable**, not just **Exception**. Those Executor/ ThreadPoolExecutor things do a poor job of logging failures & errors thrown out, that will kill a thread & never explain why.

Oh, and when you catch an Exception -- log it. Otherwise the next programmer who works on your code will have to have you whipped for your sins. Even `e.printStackTrace( System.out)` is a thousand times better than nothing.

Does the Translator work even once?  "Stuck" would imply that it did, but you're not clear. Be clear.

Try getting a stack dump in your debugger, or pressing Ctrl-Break in the console (it doesn't kill the program). Odds it won't tell you anything because a ClassNotFound has killed the thread-pool, but you might as well try.

Comment: It works most of the time, except when the internet is slow. How to catch and log Throwable?

Comment: `catch (Throwable e) {e.printStackTrace( System.err);}`.  Okay, well at least it works once -- so I guess the thread is just stuck waiting. Future.cancel() probably won't be very effective in cancelling - it just flags it as cancelled, but the thread-pool has already started it I don't think that will have much effect. Use your debugger or Ctrl-Break to see where it's hung up, then.

Comment: catching a throwable didn't do much, and how/where do you press Ctrl-Break. What is the 'Break' key?

Comment: Top-right of keyboard near Scroll-Lock.  Press it when you have the Java program's console window selected, and Java will give you a thread dump -- this shows you where threads are hung up. It doesn't kill the program from running. You can also use JVisualVM or other Java GUI tools to do similar.

Comment: Silly me. It is possible that it gets stuck, but I don't think that was the case here. It was a completely different piece of code that was causing the problem. Ctrl-break helped me find this. Thanks for your help.